# powershell compare-object file sync issue with the diff

Tags: file, object, powershell, compare, synchronization

I want to compare and sync two directories in two different locations. Using the diffs, I want to copy files from directory 1 to directory 2, and directory 2 to directory 1 (assuming each directory has files the other doesn't). I'll explain the issue with an example.

dir1: c:\john\abc

dir2: a:\mary\abc

let's say has 10 files. 1 diff.

c:\john\abc\folder\file.txt
a:\mary\abc\file.txt

If I do compare object dir1 dir2 -property name. This 1 diff doesn't show up because I'm only comparing file names. If I do compare-object dir1 dir2 property fullname then everything is a diff, so that won't work.

ok, I can get around that. I chop off the root dir path, so that I compare these:

folder\file.txt
file.txt

(2 diffs found)

Issue: How do I know which directory has the file.txt inside a folder, and which directory has file.txt in the root? (c:\john\abc vs a:\mary\abc) ?

Comment: THE $_.SIDEINDICATOR ! ! !

Comment: What's wrong with robocopy?

Comment: Have you had a look at the following article which includes Powershell tools for doing folder/file comparisons? http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/08/easily-compare-two-folders-by-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: There is a script at http://noamwajnman.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/synchronize-folderdirectory-contents/ which covers the copy files from source to destination folders. I'm sure you can adapt that script to go both ways.